Apache Ignite 2.16 Docker Image - Jmap /Jstack Command Not found to take Memory /Thread Dump
Our Application is using Apache Ignite 2.16 in Kubernetes environment as a Pod with 3 replicas.
During Load , Ignite pods are getting restarted, with Strangely the Heap Started coming down.

    Line  4207:     ^-- Heap [used=3396MB, free=57.74%, comm=3638MB]
    Line  4235:     ^-- Heap [used=3744MB, free=53.42%, comm=3996MB]
    Line  4263:     ^-- Heap [used=3972MB, free=50.57%, comm=4162MB]
    Line  4291:     ^-- Heap [used=4358MB, free=45.78%, comm=4450MB]
    Line  4319:     ^-- Heap [used=4219MB, free=47.5%, comm=4502MB]
    Line  4347:     ^-- Heap [used=4420MB, free=45%, comm=4784MB]
    Line  4375:     ^-- Heap [used=4705MB, free=41.47%, comm=5040MB]
    Line  4403:     ^-- Heap [used=4962MB, free=38.27%, comm=5290MB]
    Line  4431:     ^-- Heap [used=5200MB, free=35.3%, comm=5576MB]
    Line  4459:     ^-- Heap [used=5571MB, free=30.69%, comm=5818MB]
    Line  4489:     ^-- Heap [used=6215MB, free=22.68%, comm=6514MB]
    Line  4517:     ^-- Heap [used=6707MB, free=16.56%, comm=7054MB]
    Line  4545:     ^-- Heap [used=7186MB, free=10.6%, comm=7520MB]
    Line  4573:     ^-- Heap [used=7579MB, free=5.71%, comm=7908MB]
    Line  4604:     ^-- Heap [used=7265MB, free=9.61%, comm=8038MB]
    Line  4668:     ^-- Heap [used=7914MB, free=1.54%, comm=8038MB]
    Line  4741:     ^-- Heap [used=7964MB, free=0.92%, comm=8038MB]
    Line 10969:     ^-- Heap [used=7973MB, free=0.8%, comm=8038MB]

Other details

We dont use onHeapEnabled ,which is set as False
No Native persistence Used
No SQLIgnite Query is being fired during that time

To identify, we have been trying to Heap dump and Thread dump, but Docker Apache ignite is not having those jstack / jmap commands in it
Can somebody let me know how do we solve this issue or suggest proper docker image of Apache Ignite - Jdk 11 with these commands instead of rebuilding image

Unclear what you mean by "proper" image. It looks like you're using the official one. Best practice is to remove stuff that's not required to run, which is what the community have done. You can always add tooling by building on top of the image or with an init container.

Having said that, the logs are usually sufficient. Maybe you can share your configuration and more of the logs.

@stephen Thanks for your Reply
We have done successfully adding the JDK to the Ignite Image by following steps. Now able to take Thread dump and Heap dump
Following are the steps followed

Download the binary from the official site of Apache Ignite
Apache Link - Download
Created a Docker File to build image with the following contents
 FROM openjdk:11
 ENV IGNITE_HOME=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite
 ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/run.sh"]
 WORKDIR /opt/ignite
 COPY apache-ignite* apache-ignite 
 COPY run.sh /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/
 RUN chmod 777 -R /opt/ignite/apache-ignite




Finally Able to Take Heap dump using jstack, jmap commands

Note:
Cause : Apache Ignite Temurin Eclipse jdk
RebuildVM information:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.21+9 Eclipse
Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.21+9
which didnt have those Heap/Thread Commands.
